# How do I close a filestream after it creates a file C# .NET and not use it as a process

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I have this method for my webcam application that im currently developing and I'm having some issues with the fact that after it takes a picture you cant do anything with the picture because its being used by another process, so aslong as the application is running I cant do anything with the image on my PC because its being used by another process.. So if i try to take another picture it throws me this error..

> An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code

I tried doing stream.Close but it doesnt really change it at all.

Here I have two methods basically doing the same thing but none of them works.
Should I async & await the method or is it a bit extreme?

```
private void saveCamImage()
{
    string path;
    path = "%AppData%\\img.png"; // collection of paths
    path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);


    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)imgVideo.Source));
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }
}




private void threadImage()
{
    string path;
    path = "%AppData%\\img1.png"; // collection of paths
    path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)imgVideo.Source));

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    encoder.Save(fs);
    fs.Close();
}
```

> Additional information: The process cannot access the file
>    because it is being
>   used by another process.

Due to lack of information about the code, This is how its structured. I can take a picture and save it and if I want to I can also send it to my / someone elses email. Kinda like a very oldschool chat messanger.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using WPFCSharpWebCam;

namespace SystemSecurityFile
{
    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// Application features
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        #region methods


        WebCam webcam;
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
            webcam = new WebCam();
            webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref imgVideo);
        }

        private void saveCamImage()
        {
            string path;
            path = "%AppData%\\img.png"; // collection of paths
            path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);


            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)imgVideo.Source));
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                encoder.Save(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }

        private void threadImage()
        {
            string path;
            path = "%AppData%\\img.png"; // collection of paths
            path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)imgVideo.Source));

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            encoder.Save(fs);
        }

        #endregion

        private void initializeToolBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            threadImage();
            sendCamImage();
        }
        private void sendCamImage()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Clipboard.GetImage();
                var clipboardImage = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetImage();
                image.Source = clipboardImage;

                //string filePath = "C:\\Users\\Developer\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sys32.png";

                string path;
                path = "%AppData%\\img.png"; // collection of paths
                path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress(emailfromTextbox.Text, "Your Webcam Image");
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailTextbox.Text));
                msg.Subject = "Your Webcam Image";
                msg.Body = clipboardImage.ToString();
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html", null, "text/plain");
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Here is an embedded image.<img src=cid:companylogo>", null, "text/html");

                //create the LinkedResource (embedded image)
                LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(path);
                logo.ContentId = "img.png";
                //add the LinkedResource to the appropriate view
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

                msg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailTextbox.Text, emailpasswordTextbox.Text);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(msg);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("wDone");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "wGMAIL");

                string path;
                path = "%AppData%\\img.png"; // collection of paths
                path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

                var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)image.Source));
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    encoder.Save(stream);

                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Made it down here");
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Your codes seem to be OK. How do you invoke them? how many threads do you have?

Comment: Maybe try `using (SmtpClientsmtp = new SmtpClient())`? And `LinkedResource ` is also disposable.

Answer (score -1):

You should use both streams in a `using` clause. This disposes the stream (by calling `dispose()` which is a method of `IDisposable`)

As you've noted, `close` does nothing, since you already used the `using` statement and thus disposed the steam, making the `close` call obsolete.

Comment: Im not using both of them, I've tried with both, usually one of them is commented out when I try to run the code.

So I should call stream.dispose?

Comment: The using(stream ...) {} Disposes the stream automatically at the end of the block, so you should not do that yourself. It is unclear that you haven't used close, since it is in the code you posted

Comment: Since the using(stream...)
{} does it for me what do I do?

Comment: You should just save the encoder data into the file, just like you did.

Comment: Didnt I do that in the methods above? Those are the ones giving me the errors.

Comment: I can't tell because you only posted a small portion of your code. Possibly if it's a multi threading issue, a lock around the function may help